# Display an integer with a comma: 30000 --> 30,000

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

How do I display an integer within a UILabel with a comma?

Like this:
30000 --> 30,000

My English is not that good so I did not know what to search for.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the NSNumberFormatter and do just few things as :

```
NSInteger integerValue=30000;
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatterComma = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[numberFormatterComma setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSString *formatted = [numberFormatterComma stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:integerValue]];
NSLog(@"--> %@",formatted);
```

Now you can put the `formatted` string to your label.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at NSNumberFormatter

Here is an example

```
    self.numberFormat = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];  

        //set up formatter for display text
    [self.numberFormat setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [self.numberFormat setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundFloor];
    [self.numberFormat setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
    [self.numberFormat setMinimumIntegerDigits:1];
    [self.numberFormat setMaximumFractionDigits:24];
    [self.numberFormat setMaximumSignificantDigits:24];

    NSString* formattedText = 
     [self.numberFormat stringFromNumber:[self.numberFormat numberFromString:rawString]];
```

Take care not to alloc/init them often, they are quite heavy objects. Best to create once and keep in a property for reuse. If you are making OSX apps (as opposed to ios) you get formatting objects in Interface Builder also, you can drag them around and set their parameters in the attributes inspector.

Comment: On OS X, you can even drag a formatter into your nib and then wire up a field to it, so that the field's object value will be a number, rather than a string.

Answer (score 0):

// Comma seperated numeric conversion

```
-(NSString*)convertNumericIntoCommaSeperatedValue:(NSString*)string{

NSNumberFormatter *frmtr = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[frmtr setGroupingSize:3];

[frmtr setGroupingSeparator:@","];

[frmtr setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];

NSString *commaSeperatedString = [frmtr stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[string longLongValue]]];

[frmtr release],frmtr=nil;

return commaSeperatedString;
}
```

Comment: That's the hard way, and ignorant of different locales' thousands-separator styles. See Anoop Vaidya's answer for a much simpler implementation that might be (and could easily be made, if it isn't already) locale-aware.